# Powershell get "-command" switch value in script

Tags: powershell, command-line, parameters

When calling a script from command line
how can i get the tokens passed after the "-command" switch (or -file)
(raw strings... independent from params()... as args[] in C)

I mean... the script name and the script parameters

$args do not show these values
$MyInvocation also not giving this data

THX!

Comment: Why? What problem are you solving?

Comment: Use [`[CmdletsBinding]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I need to know what is passed in the '-command' or '-file' parameter to change some variables in the PowerShell profile script

Comment: But why though? What do you want to do?

Comment: I build dynamic environments analysing the powershell script name string... "acgt-kk-*" scripts has some defined data already in the environment... "acgt-rr-**" has different data defined by the profile script... etc. etc. and the special case of no-script name (no -command <script> in the command line> has other special environment with some modules loaded by the profile script... se the users will have a simple command language created by me to handle data... ;-) I hope the explanation it was not too confusing... ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: Your question and explanation are utterly unintelligible (I suspect a language barrier).

Comment: Sorry Bill... I put the text I wrote in the google translator (portuguese is my native language) and everything comes OK... I agree that what I'm trying to explain it is a bit complex... Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the raw command line arguments, you'll need to retrieve the `CommandLine` property of the associated `Win32_Process` wmi instance:

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID").CommandLine
```

Comment: thanks Mathias... great info there.. (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = $PID") | select * ... I wonder if we can get this info from powershell environment without recurring to WMI (using cross-platform  I think Win32_Process will not be available)

Comment: also I would like to obtain only the command-line invoked script data... [0]=script-full-path... and [1..n] the args passed to the script...  this 2 items resume to everything passed after the "-command" or "-file" command-line switch... so it should be available in the powershell environment!!!

Comment: I get almost all the info you pointed with " Get-Process -Id $PID | select * " ... it fails fot not providing the arguments that were present in the command line at powershell.exe invocation--- :(

Comment: Hi Matias,,, I've accepted your answer because I found no other solution for the problem of  inspecting the command line from inside the profile(s) script(s)... Thanks!